# Using Mann-Whitney U in Python: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, scipy

I'm doing pairwise tests for my data using using Mann-Whitney U.

```
  for x in myData:
      for y in myData:
          d_value, p_value = ks_2samp(x, y) #two-tailed p-value
          u_value, p_value1 = mannwhitneyu(x, y, use_continuity=True) #One-sided p-value
```

I got an error at this line:

```
u_value, p_value1 = mannwhitneyu(x, y, use_continuity=True)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I don't know what I'm missing here ? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like you have used the name `mannwhitneyu` to name a `list`, somewhere early in your code.

Comment: Exactly, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in you program, you named a `list` called `mannwhitneyu`. Since `mannwhitneyu` is now a list, you can no long call it as a function. Try finding the list in question and changing its name to `mannwhitneyuList`. This will solve your problem, because now Python no longer associates the name `mannwhitneyu` with a list, meaning that it now points to the intended function.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and you help